# audio pause in xamarin.forms C#

Tags: audio, xamarin.forms

So i am building an app using xamarin.forms which needs to play and control audio. I have currently got my audio file playing on both android and iOS BUT I can't get other controls to work such as .Pause() and .Stop()

Playing audio works in both examples.

I thank you in advance!

Here is my code for each platform

ANDROID:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AudioPlayEx.Droid;
using AudioToolbox;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.OS;
using Android;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]
namespace AudioPlayEx.Droid
{
    public class AudioService : IAudio
    {
        public AudioService()
        {
        }

        MediaPlayer player;

        public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
        {
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
            player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };
            player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            player.Prepare();
        }

        protected MediaPlayer playme;
        public void PauseAudioFile(String fileName)
        {
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
            player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                player.Pause();
            };
            player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            player.Prepare();
        }

    }
}
```

iOS:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AudioPlayEx;
using AudioPlayEx.iOS;
using System.IO;
using Foundation;
using AVFoundation;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]
namespace AudioPlayEx.iOS
{
    public class AudioService : IAudio
    {
        public AudioService()
        {
        }

        public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
        {
            string sFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
            var url = NSUrl.FromString(sFilePath);
            var _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
            _player.FinishedPlaying += (object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) => {
                _player = null;
            };
            _player.Play();
        }


        public void PauseAudioFile(string fileName)
        {
            string sFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
            var url = NSUrl.FromString(sFilePath);
            var _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
            _player.Pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to save your instance of AVAudioPlayer to a variable and call pause on that object. Right now you're creating a new AVAudioPlayer and calling pause on it, which is doing nothing. I've added iOS code to show what I mean. Android should be similar.

iOS:

```
public class AudioService : IAudio
{
    AVAudioPlayer _player;

    public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
    {
        string sFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
        var url = NSUrl.FromString(sFilePath);
        _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
        _player.FinishedPlaying += (object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) => {
            _player = null;
        };
        _player.Play();
    }


    public void PauseAudioFile(string fileName)
    {
        _player.Pause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That topic is old, but I did it that way:

```
MediaPlayer player;

        public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName, string ONOF)
        {
           
            if (ONOF == "OFF")
            {
                player.Stop();
            }

            if (ONOF == "ON")
                    {
                 player = new MediaPlayer();
                var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
                player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
                {
                    
                        player.Start(); 
                   
                };
                player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
                player.Prepare();
           }

        }
```