# C# Android pause audio file

Tags: c#, android, audio, xamarin.android

I'm building an app using xamarin.forms which needs to play and control audio. I have currently got my audio file playing but I can't get the other controls to work such as .Pause() Does anybody have an Ide what I have been doing wrong? Thanks in advance! :)

The debbuger says that the button is working so my guess Is that there is something wrong with the PauseAudioFile function.

I used this example for my own code. [audio pause in xamarin.forms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973907/audio-pause-in-xamarin-forms-c-sharp)

```
public class SoundDependency : ISound
{
    public SoundDependency() { }

    MediaPlayer player;

    public void startSound(string fileName)
    {

        var player = new MediaPlayer(); // Create media player
        var assetFile = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName); // Open the resource

        // Hook up some events

        player.Prepared += (sender, args) =>
        {
            player.Start();
        };
        player.SetDataSource(assetFile.FileDescriptor, assetFile.StartOffset, assetFile.Length);
        player.Prepare();
    }

    public void PauseAudioFile(string fileName)
    {

        if (player != null)
        {
            player.Pause();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing if-else in `PauseAudioFile(...)`

Comment: Sorry It didnt work, app died instead when I pressed the  Pause button. My error message is "object reference notset to an instance of an object with the PauseAudioFile function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed "var" from "var player = new MediaPlayer();" so now it works!

```
public class SoundDependency : ISound
{
    public SoundDependency() { }

    MediaPlayer player;

    public void startSound(string fileName)
    {

        player = new MediaPlayer(); // Create media player
        var assetFile = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName); // Open the resource

        // Hook up some events

        player.Prepared += (sender, args) =>
        {
            player.Start();
        };
        player.SetDataSource(assetFile.FileDescriptor, assetFile.StartOffset, assetFile.Length);
        player.Prepare();
    }

    public void PauseAudioFile(string fileName)
    {

        if (player != null)
        {
            player.Pause();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: that was horrible